# Setting up a private Ethereum network and integrate it with Hyperledger Caliper

Tags: go-ethereum, private, benchmark

I hope you're alright and safe there.

I'm trying to set up a private Ethereum network and bind it to Hyperledger Caliper. However, I couldn't sufficient sources to do that. Recently, I used geth v1.19 Ethereum client and created two nodes, initialised them with the same genesis.json file. But I couldn't go beyond that point. I tried to bind it to Caliper and the error I got as the following.

ethereum@ethereum-VirtualBox:~/caliper-benchmarks$ npx caliper launch master     --caliper-workspace .     --caliper-benchconfig benchmarks/scenario/simple/config.yaml     --caliper-networkconfig networks/ethereum/1node/ethereum.json
2020.09.26-02:18:31.025 info  [caliper] [cli-launch-master]     Set workspace path: /home/ethereum/caliper-benchmarks
2020.09.26-02:18:31.028 info  [caliper] [cli-launch-master]     Set benchmark configuration path: /home/ethereum/caliper-benchmarks/benchmarks/scenario/simple/config.yaml
2020.09.26-02:18:31.029 info  [caliper] [cli-launch-master]     Set network configuration path: /home/ethereum/caliper-benchmarks/networks/ethereum/1node/ethereum.json
2020.09.26-02:18:31.029 info  [caliper] [cli-launch-master]     Set SUT type: ethereum
2020.09.26-02:18:32.106 info  [caliper] [benchmark-validator]   No observer specified, will default to `none`
2020.09.26-02:18:32.106 info  [caliper] [caliper-engine]    Starting benchmark flow
2020.09.26-02:18:32.154 error [caliper] [cli-launch-master]     Unexpected error during benchmark execution: Error: Ethereum benchmarks must not use http(s) RPC connections, as there is no way to guarantee the order of submitted transactions when using other transports. For more information, please see https://github.com/hyperledger/caliper/issues/776#issuecomment-624771622

I may not achieve to set up a proper private Ethereum network for Caliper. I would be grateful if you could help me out with testing the private Ethereum network with Caliper.

My email: znkcn2000@gmail.com

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Go to the network settings file (networks/ethereum/1node/ethereum.json) and replace the following line

```
"url": "http://localhost:8545",
```

with

```
"url": "ws://localhost:8545",
```

Make sure you use the correct port number.

Good Luck